# Lunar society and survival of technobarbarian survivors of space-ship crash

Tags: society, space, post-apocalypse, space-colonization

**The Premise**

Generations and generations ago, interstellar war engulfed an earthlike system. One casualty of this war was a sizeable vessel that was crippled and crash-landed on a moon orbiting an earth-like world. Left for dead, distress beacon destroyed, and planet beneath them a wartorn hellhole, the survivors elected to settle down for the long haul on the lunar surface.

Scoot forwards a couple of centuries, and their once-spacefaring society has devolved into something approximating Dark Age Europe with sufficiently advanced technology as required for believable survival.

Established technologies include but aren't limited to handmade voidsuits and pressurised 'longhouses' (which they have the knowledge to produce more of), and genetically modified void-suitable plants for agriculture and limited high-tech craft for raiding planet-borne survivors and limited atmosphere/resource-harvesting from the world below (which they have knowledge enough to maintain, but not the knowledge/facilities to produce more of).

**The Question**

What are the most pressing difficulties a society such as this would need to overcome?

So far, I have:

- Muscle and bone-wastage from low gravity, and other nasty physiological effects. Mitigated somewhat by steroid-laced genetically-modified crops, and a little by some low-level genetic modification of themselves to make them suitable for long-distance spaceflight (in the distant past).
- Harvesting of breathable atmosphere. Presumably it would be easier from the upper atmosphere, as far from the gravity well as possible. Valuable resource.
- Abrasive lunar regolith. Could it conceivably melt and form a solid, relatively dust-free crater from a space-borne weapon impact?
- Travelling to the
- Any other issues I've missed? I've read through a host of other 'lunar survival' questions and think I've covered most of it.

Comment: Don't forget radiation! Without proper shielding, at the very least the constant radiation would make the population sterile.

Comment: The four-part question seems very, very broad. Whole-books-full-of-speculation kind of broad.

Comment: My first test: Trash and sewage disposal. Folks make a lot of it, it stinks, and some of it simply cannot be recycled. My second test is water and oxygen...which means fuel for those collector ships. Rocket fuel requires collecting a LOT of energy, and complex chemistry to convert that energy into fuel. That's a vast infrastructure - many of those barbarians are going to be quite skilled industrial engineers, chemical engineers, and mechanical engineers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys :) you're right, it is 'The Martian' level broad, but some extra thought and input is very helpful.

Comment: On the one hand easy space travel isn't really an issue. I should have mentioned that this is couched in the 40k universe, so easy access to high-tech and durable landing craft without knowledge to make them won't break people's suspension of disbelief, although added realism is always a plus. Disposal of waste is interesting though. Biological wadte I suppose could feasibly fertilise void-crops. What other waste would need to be dealt with?

Comment: This question is way, way, way too broad, and that means you'll get low quality answers.  Please seriously consider deleting this question and re-submitting four questions.  Try to word the questions so there can be one best answer.  ("what is the greatest difficulty to overcome?" vs "what difficulties must they overcome?", the first has one best answer.  The second would be closed as primarily opinion-based.).

Comment: Thanks, I'll narrow this particular question to the first question only.

Comment: Pregnancy and childhood will probably not work under low gravity. In Artemis, the Moon city is forbidden to children and pregnant women have to go back to Earth to avoid catastrophic health effects. This may be solved by having the original survivors been genetically modified to avoid low/zero-g health problems.

Comment: Also note that Dark Age Europe was invented wholesale by smug Enlightenment scholars who wanted to have a previous age to look down, despite the fact that their time became actually even less sanitary and more violent. Unless you are talking about what followed the Bronze Age Collapse one or two millennia before, though this would be a bit further south-east.

Answer (score 1):

Asteroids impacts would pose a threat, there is a reason why earth moon (and just about every other moon we have a good enough picture of) is full of impact craters, without an atmosphere earth moon is a lot more susceptible to being hit by asteroids - you could possibly have your moon homes shielded in some way to reduce that risk, or maybe have "lasers" blow them up before they hit.

Solar radiation is another problem, the earth has a magnetic field that deflects most of the radiation but our moon doesn't & it's safe to assume the same will be true for your world and moon - your moon dwellers could create their own magnetic field to save themselves from radiation related affects.

Solar flares - you will need to have some sort of protection or risk frying all of the civilization in one solar flare event, they are rare but seeing how your question states centuries it's likely at least one happened during that time

Emigration might be an unexpected risk for your society, You state that your people go planet side to raid it & while it may be a hellhole it will likely still have a large appeal to a large number of the people who didn't chose to crash on the moon.

Lack of salt, couldn't find any mention on there being salt on the moon & your lunar surface might be of a different composure anyway but if your moon doesn't have any salt in it your people are going to have to get it through raids

blood pressure might also pose a problem - there is no data on human born & live in space (duh) but I imagine that a human heart that is used to low G only might be in for quite a shock once it lands on a 1G planet surface and then have to do a lot of intensive work (such as raiding)